# How to return aggregated document from MongoDB in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to aggregate field `category` (which is actually an `ObjectId`, but I found it more convinient to work if it is `string`) in my pretty generic blog post model:

```
type Post struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID       `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title       *string                  `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Slug        *string                  `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
    Content     []map[string]interface{} `json:"content" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    Category    *string                  `json:"category" bson:"category,omitempty"`
}
```

I have this pipeline:

```
match := bson.D{
    {
        "$match", bson.D{
            {
                "slug", slug,
            },
        },
    },
}

lookup := bson.D{
    {
        "$lookup", bson.D{
            {
                "from", categories.Model_name,
            },
            {
                "localField", "category",
            },
            {
                "foreignField", "_id",
            },
            {
                "as", "category",
            },
        },
    },
}

unwind := bson.D{
    {
        "$unwind", bson.D{
            {
                "path", "$category",
            },
        },
    },
}

cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{match, lookup, unwind})

var results []Post
if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &results); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

But I am getting this error: `panic: error decoding key category: cannot decode array into a string type`.

And yeah, it's kinda clear that in my struct `category` field is just a string and I am trying to put there other type, but what I have to do? I think that creating another struct for this case would be at least inefficient. Let's say if in another function I will want to aggregate another field? Another struct will be needed?

Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing the pipeline thing right, because with that unwind stage the `results` are empty. If I exclude that stage, I got my results but couldn't decode them.

And I have to mention that the goal is just to get **single** document from collection and aggregate `category` field, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way?

P.S. Feel free to criticize my code because I just started my Go journey, I'm not sure about everything :)

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the category is an array instead of just a string.

Your current definition:

```
type Post struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID       `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title       *string                  `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Slug        *string                  `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
    Content     []map[string]interface{} `json:"content" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    Category    *string                  `json:"category" bson:"category,omitempty"`
}
```

Should look like:

```
type Post struct {
    ID          primitive.ObjectID       `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title       *string                  `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Slug        *string                  `json:"slug" bson:"slug"`
    Content     []map[string]interface{} `json:"content" bson:"content,omitempty"`
    Category    []*string                  `json:"category" bson:"category,omitempty"`
}
```

Where `Category []*string` might still need some tweaking:
The pointer to string could also just be a string.

(Not knowing this return from Mongo and not having one running to test):

Another option is that the category is a byte array, and that the type has to be []byte.

Comment: Yes, but in the other function I don't do aggregation and need to return **category** as a string (ObjectID). If I change `Category` type to `[]*string`, I will get error there

Comment: You will have to preparse the data to determine the exact type you are going to unmarshal it in, or go []byte/json.RawMessage and execute an evaluation of the exact type on Category later